# How to solve çontinue not properly in loop in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am new to coding and am trying my hand at webscraping data from google maps. I found a code online and tried to run it on Jupyter but kept receiving the continue not properly in loop error message in one of the functions. It seemed fine in theory (to my knowledge), but it's just not working.

```
def scrape(self, url):
    try:
        self.driver.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        self.driver.quit()
        continue
    time.sleep(10)

    self.click_open_close_time()
    self.get_location_data()
    self.get_location_open_close_time()
    self.get_popular_times()
    if(self.click_all_reviews_button()==False):
        continue
    time.sleep(5)
    self.scroll_the_page()
    self.expand_all_reviews()
    self.get_reviews_data()
    self.driver.quit()

    return(self.location_data)
```

Comment: [`continue`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm#:~:text=The%20continue%20statement%20in%20Python,both%20while%20and%20for%20loops.) can only be inside of the loop. What is your `continue` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

`continue` is only allowed within a `for` or `while` loop. Hence the `SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop`.

You can read more about the `continue` statement in Python documentation: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=continue#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)